# How chrome extension monitor the page totally display event?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

how chrome extension monitor the page totally display event? I need to know the time from start(which i can get) to the page displayed completely. I can only get the load time, can not find any way to capture the event when the page become static(especially html5 webpage).Thx

Comment: Many pages never become static.

Answer (score 0):

Use the window performance API `window.performance.timing` it will give you all the timestamps of the significant events in pages load.

for example

```
connectEnd: 1446672490568
connectStart: 1446672490568
domComplete: 1446672490685
domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1446672490681
domContentLoadedEventStart: 1446672490680
domInteractive: 1446672490680
domLoading: 1446672490603
domainLookupEnd: 1446672490568
domainLookupStart: 1446672490568
fetchStart: 1446672490568
loadEventEnd: 1446672490685
loadEventStart: 1446672490685
navigationStart: 1446672490262
redirectEnd: 0
redirectStart: 0
requestStart: 1446672490597
responseEnd: 1446672490603
responseStart: 1446672490601
secureConnectionStart: 0
unloadEventEnd: 0
unloadEventStart: 0
__proto__: PerformanceTiming
```

To get this data from every page via a chrome extension you will need to inject this script into every page via a content script that is executed after page load.